# select2 MULTIPLE placeholder does not work

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2, placeholder

I'm using the following piece of code to select item but placeholder already is not visible. I am using this example [select2-bootstrap](http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/)

```
   <div class="form-group" style="width:70px; height:44px;">
  <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id="select2" placeholder="cawky parky">
    <option>ahoj</option>
    <option>more</option>
    <option>ideme</option>
    <option>na </option>
    <option>pivo?</option>
  </select>
</div>
  <script src="//select2.github.io/select2/select2-3.4.2/select2.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#select2").select2({
    multiple:true,
    placeholder: "haha",
});
```

Comment: plus 1 for great options :D

Answer (score 33):

**2020 solution**

The big issue here, is the first option of your select + your placeholder, being too big to fit in the dropdown. And so, select2 will force the placeholder to be **width:0;**.

This can be fixed with the following two lines of CSS, which will override this select2 "feature":

```
.select2-search--inline {
    display: contents; /*this will make the container disappear, making the child the one who sets the width of the element*/
}

.select2-search__field:placeholder-shown {
    width: 100% !important; /*makes the placeholder to be 100% of the width while there are no options selected*/
}
```

**Be aware** that the `:placeholder-shown` pseudo-class will not work in the oldest versions of some browsers, as well as on IE, as you can check [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aplaceholder-shown).

Answer (score 27):

After hours of trying to figure this out I noticed that when the select is initially rendered the width of .select2-search__field is 0px. When I selected an option and then removed the option, the placeholder is shown and the width was about 1000px.

So to fix this I did the following:

```
$('.search-select-multiple').select2({
    dropdownAutoWidth: true,
    multiple: true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '30px',
    placeholder: "Select",
    allowClear: true
});
$('.select2-search__field').css('width', '100%');
```

Comment: I also found that after resetting the value `$("#select2").val(null).trigger('change');`, you have to run this last line to fix the placeholder.

Comment: I had to do a slightly different version of this: `$('.select2-selection__rendered > li, .select2-search__field').css('width', '100%');`

Comment: FYI, I had to delay it, e.g. `setTimeout(function() { $('.select2-search__field').css('width', '100%'); }, 0);` - what a PITA.

Answer (score 19):

Add This In Your Script File:

```
$('select').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    placeholder: function(){
        $(this).data('placeholder');
    }
}):
```

In HTML add This:

```
<select data-placeholder="Yours Placeholder" multiple>
    <option>Value 1</option>
    <option>Value 2</option>
    <option>Value 3</option>
    <option>Value 4</option>
    <option>Value 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `data-placeholder` in the element HTML is all that is necessary.

Comment: @Madbreaks For documentation of this fuctionality of select 2's https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes

Answer (score 11):

Just use data-placeholder instead of placeholder.

```
<div class="form-group" style="width:70px; height:44px;">
    <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id="select2" data-placeholder="cawky parky">
        <option>ahoj</option>
        <option>more</option>
        <option>ideme</option>
        <option>na </option>
        <option>pivo?</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your script file:

```
$("select").each(function(i,v){
    var that = $(this);
    var placeholder = $(that).attr("data-placeholder");
    $(that).select2({
        placeholder:placeholder
    });
});
```

in your html (add data-placeholder="Your text"):

```
<select data-placeholder="Yours Placeholder" multiple>
    <option>Value A</option>
    <option>Value B</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, placeholder seems to require `allowClear: true` and object mode. Try the following to see if it works. See https://codepen.io/louking/pen/BGMvRP?# for generic examples using yadcf (sorry for the extra complexity, but I believe yadcf passes select_type_options directly to select2).

```
$("#select2").select2({
    multiple:true,
    allowClear:true,
    placeholder: {
      id: -1
      text: "haha"
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a [closed issue on the select2 GitHub](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4220#issuecomment-705855505) but it was never really resolved in the library itself.

My solution is similar to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61059820/1307183) presented by [Pedro Figueiredo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11102792/pedro-figueiredo), except it does not make the container disappear. There is a [note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) about `display: contents` which could cause some accessibility issues. You can simply switch that to a 100% width as well:

```
.select2-search--inline,
.select2-search__field:placeholder-shown {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

I prefer and find it slightly cleaner to set the styles based on the `.select2-container` so I can then call standard HTML elements, like so:

```
.select2-container li:only-child,
.select2-container input:placeholder-shown {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Either set of code accesses the same elements either way, and I'm not sure which one is more 'future proof'; for now it is a matter of preference.

Also if you're using tabs you might need to throw in a

```
.select2-container {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

or else select2 fields might not be the proper width when switching to tabs that aren't displayed by default.

Answer (score 0):

In your html

```
      <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id="select2">
             <option selected="selected">cawky parky</option>
             <option>ahoj</option>
             <option>more</option>
             <option>ideme</option>
             <option>na </option>
             <option>pivo?</option>   
    </select>
```

in your jquery

```
$(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: "Selecione",
    allowClear: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way, when I attach to select2 to dom than
$('.select2-search__field').width('100%') change to width style with it $('.select2-search__field').width('100%')

```
function setSelect(select, data, placeholder) {
select.each(function () {
    let $this = $(this)
    $this.wrap('<div class="position-relative"></div>')
    $this.select2({
        placeholder,
        allowClear: true,
        dropdownParent: $this.parent(),
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        data
    })
})
$('.select2-search__field').width('100%')
```

}

Answer (score 0):

##### select2/3.5.4

In your CSS:

```js
.select2-search-field, .select2-search-field input[placeholder] {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Select2 4.0.1 still doesn't work for me for multiple selects.

My solution

HTML

```
<select class="select-2" multiple>
   ...
</select>
```

JS

```
$('.select-2').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: -1,
    placeholder: function(){
        $(this).data('placeholder');
    }
});
$('.select-2[multiple]').each(function() {
   $(this).next('.select2').find('textarea').attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
});

$('.select2-search__field').css('width', '100%');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

[Open this image for the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikdDS.png)

in your javascript

```
$('.select2-search__field').addClass('w-100')
```

or

```
$('.select2-search__field').css('width', '100%')
```

Answer (score -1):

placeholder tag is not valid attribute for select list

you can use something like this:

```
       <select class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" id="select2">
                 <option selected="selected">cawky parky</option>
                 <option>ahoj</option>
                 <option>more</option>
                 <option>ideme</option>
                 <option>na </option>
                 <option>pivo?</option>   
        </select>
```

Then write proper jquery

In your [select2-Bootstrap](http://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/) example is totaly different structure

Comment: can you rewrite jquery for me please ?

Answer (score -1):

I have some select2 inputs inside bootstrap tabs.
The solution that works for me:

```
.select2-search--inline {
    display: contents; /*this will make the container disappear, making the child the one who sets the width of the element*/
}

.select2-search__field:placeholder-shown {
    width: 100% !important; /*makes the placeholder to be 100% of the width while there are no options selected*/
}
```