# Select2 does not show placeholder if initially hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

When using Select2 on initially hidden `<select>` with multiple attribute, the placeholder does not show up. Looking at the code I can see that selector `.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field` has a 0px width (guess because it's hidden).

```js
$('[data-trigger="open"]').on('click', function(){
 $('[data-target="open"]').toggleClass('hidden');
})

$('.select2').select2({
 width: '100%'
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="#" data-trigger="open">Open Select2 and watch no placeholder...</a></p>
<div class="hidden" data-target="open">
  <select name="select" id="select" class="select2" multiple data-placeholder="Select one or more...">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Forcing a `width: 100% !important` CSS rule only partially fixes the problem: the placeholder shows up but the input field grows too much with every item selection

```js
$('[data-trigger="open"]').on('click', function(){
 $('[data-target="open"]').toggleClass('hidden');
})

$('.select2').select2({
 width: '200px' // limit size to make the "growing "problem appear
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none;
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="#" data-trigger="open">Open Select2: placeholder ok, but field grows abnormally when inserting items...</a></p>
<div class="hidden" data-target="open">
  <select name="select" id="select" class="select2" multiple data-placeholder="Select one or more...">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Please, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the placeholder gets removed when you have the div as hidden by default.

Look at the example below.

```js
$('[data-trigger="open"]').on('click', function() {
  $('[data-target="open"]').toggleClass('hidden');
})

$('.select2').select2({
  width: '100%',
  placeholder: function() {
    $(this).data('placeholder');
  }
});

$('.select2').parent().addClass("hidden")
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<p><a href="#" data-trigger="open">Open Select2 and watch no placeholder...</a></p>
<div class="" data-target="open">
  <select name="select" id="select" class="select2" multiple data-placeholder="Select one or more...">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! On Bootstrap I tuned the script to be used with 'shown.bs.collapse' event on a Collapsible element

Answer (score 19):

Add Below css to your page

```css
.select2-selection--multiple .select2-search__field{
  width:100%!important;
}
```

Comment: Spent way too much time trying to figure this one out. This fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: Better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140705/select2-multiple-placeholder-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Added an additional css class for those who might need it:

```css
.select2-search.select2-search--inline {
  width: 100% !important;
}
.select2-selection--multiple .select2-search__field{
  width: 100% !important;
}
```